# Changing variable values within If statements

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to take some user input defined variables to decide whether or not to enter the loop and execute a copy and rename followed by deletion of the original file as it will no longer be needed.

```
set /p multiTune="Does your tune file need to be shared with multiple 
Element sequences? (y/n) "
Echo Multi Tune is %multiTune%
if "%multiTune%"=="y" (set /p tuneCount="How many sequences will need to share your tune file? ")
Echo Tune count is %tuneCount%
pause
if "%multiTune%"=="y" (SET /p tuneName="Enter the file letter/number combination for the R quant of your tune file. ") else (@ECHO The user specified there is no need for a second tune.)
Echo Tune Name is %tuneName%
pause
if "%multiTune%"=="y" (SET /a tuneCount+=1) else(set /a tuneCount-=tuneCount)
Echo Tune count is now %tuneCount%
pause
:loop 
if "%tuneCount%"=="0" goto exitloop
Set /p seqNumber="Enter the number for one of the sequences." 
copy %tuneName%.D.pdf "S%seqNumber%-TUN1_%tuneName%.D.pdf" 
echo %tuneName%.D.pdf renamed to S%seqNumber%-TUN1_%tuneName%.D.pdf
pause
Set /a tuneCount-=1
if "%tuneCount%"=="1" DEL "%tuneName%.D.pdf"
if "%tuneCount%"==1 goto exitloop
Echo %tuneCount%
pause
goto loop
:exitloop
```

All of the echos and pauses are just for testing purposes to make sure I have the correct values in my variables.
The batch file runs fine with the variables containing the correct strings and values up until the line:

```
if "%multiTune%"=="y" (SET /a tuneCount+=1) else(set /a tuneCount-=tuneCount)
```

The file says something is unexpected and closes at this point so i havent gotten a chance to figure out if the looped portion even works. The point of the +1 is so that it enters the loop and executes the commands until it gets to 1 and skips the loop if it equals 0.

I read a bunch of information about setlocal delayedexpansion and using !'s around variables instead of %'s. I'm not sure how to implement this or if this applies to my problem at all. I know there is probably an easier way to do the if statements but I'm a novice and that was the easiest way for me to understand it as I've been learning on the fly through trial and error, and everything you see is the results of a single day of learning.

Any help would be much appreciated. I tried to be as detailed as possible about what it is I'm trying to do but if you have any questions I will do my best to answer.

Comment: You need to have a space after the `ELSE` and before the `(`. This is straight from the help file for the `IF` command: **) ELSE (**.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that. I feel really dumb. I guess that's what i get for writing it in notepad. Thanks, good eye!

Comment: What else would you write it in?

Comment: @CatCat Notepad ++ `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you are making the things so **MUCH complicated**...

Have a corrected piece of the code you provided us (*Note: I did not touch the `loop` subroutine to be on-topic*):

```bat
@echo off

choice /m "Does your tune file need to be shared with multiple element sequences? (y/n) " /C:yn /N
rem Echo Multi Tune is %errorlevel%
rem If errorlevel equals to 1 user input is "Y", it is 2 it is "N". (I commented the "echo" command as it changes the errorlevel value).

if errorlevel 2 goto question_N
if errorlevel 1 goto question_Y

:question_Y
set /p tuneCount="How many sequences will need to share your tune file? "
set /p tuneName="Enter the file letter/number combination for the R quant of your tune file. "
SET /a "tuneCount+=1"
goto loop

:question_N
set /p tuneCount="How many sequences will need to share your tune file? "
ECHO The user specified there is no need for a second tune.
set /a "tuneCount-=tuneCount"
goto loop

:loop
rem [Code you provided above]
```

I hope you are fine with this, testing it and it works!